# IIS redirect subdomain to other local server

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have two server with IIS sites on it.

1. XXX.YYY.Z.10 (to sites)
2. XXX.YYY.Z.20 (one site)

I have also domain.com forwarded to my public IP and NAT forwarded all to first (.10) server, which has 2 sites on it. It works great. I would like to open worldwide my 3rd site which is localized to second server (.20). When I add DNS A record for my2site.domain.com to my IP I see only main site from IIS. When I shut down my second server I also see that site, so I think I see default site from server one (.10). How can I redirect from there address Mysore.domain.com to my next server (XXX.YYY.Z.20)? Some URL rewrite?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, do you want to redirect from one url to another? If yes, please post detailed information, or do you want to use a reverse proxy? if yes, you can refer to this link: [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

Comment: Clearly. I have two servers A and B. My domain have DNS record to server A and there I have my site. On server B I have my second site. I want to forward subdomain address like  mysecondsite.domain.com to open webpage from server B, so I want to forward on IIS in server A to open address mysecondsite.domain.com as server B (now it opens default page from server A).Its little difficult to explain that for me.

Comment: You can try to use a reverse proxy.